# Quick sort for very large data set issue

Tags: python, quicksort

I am creating pyscript that quick sorts an array. Sounds simple, but I am struggling with it. The array I have has a length of over 7000. I used the line:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
```

which allows for python to execute any recursive code up to 100000 times. So its not a recursive limit error. However, when I used my quicksort method, any code following the quicksort method is never executed.
It's not a broken infinite loop either because the prompt displays an entry point for me to input my next line of code or a exit code 0 message. 
I ran it in pycharm and in the command prompt and still any code following the quicksort, such as a simple print(1) does not work. I copied and pasted my quicksort into a different file and tested it against a smaller sample of data and it works just as intended. Does anyone have any insight as what I can do fix the issue?

This is my quickSort method:

```
def partition(arr, arr2, low, high):  
    i = low - 1  
    pivot = arr[high]  
    for j in range(low, high):  
        if arr[j] <= pivot:  
            i = i + 1  
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]  
            arr2[i], arr2[j] = arr2[j], arr2[i]  
    arr[i + 1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i + 1]  
    arr2[i + 1], arr2[high] = arr2[high], arr2[i + 1]  
    return i + 1  


def sort(arr, arr2, low, high):  
    if low < high:  
        pi = partition(arr, arr2, low, high)  
        sort(arr, arr2, low, pi - 1)  
        sort(arr, arr2, pi + 1, high)
```

Comment: What is `arr2` in the `sort` function?

Comment: Why do you need 2 lists for quick sorting?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to figure out where exactly the code is stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes:

```
    i = low                 # low instead of low-1
# ...
    if arr[j] < pivot:      # < instead of <=
# ...
    arr[i],   arr[high] =  arr[high],  arr[i]   # i instead of i+1
    arr2[i], arr2[high] = arr2[high], arr2[i]   # i instead of i+1
```